# HTML - Wrapping td in div

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2, v-for

Using vue I dynamically create multiple `td` elements with v-for.

```
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td v-for="(item, index) in navLinks" :key="index">
        <span v-if="item.vif">
          <router-link
            :to="{ name: item.name }"
            class="router-links"
            style="margin-left: 0rem;"
            exact
          >{{ item.text }}</router-link>
        </span>
        <span v-if="showPipe(item, index)">|</span>
        <span v-if="showMargin(item, index)"></span>
      </td> 
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Now I want to wrap all tds in another html element, without creating another table. Is this possible?

Comment: "_Wrapping td in div_" That would be invalid HTML. Only permitted parent for a `<td>` is `<tr>`

Comment: And is there another possiblility?

Comment: Another possiblility for what exactly? What is your end goal?

Comment: I want exactly that td element to be in a v-if directive.

Comment: You can use `v-if` on the `<td>`

Comment: If this is the only possibility, I'd do it... But then there are like 10 tds with v-if directives...

Comment: Really not sure what you're after here, but you can use `<template v-for=".."><td>..</td><td>..</td></template>` to use v-for and v-if without using another html element around your `<td>`s